# Weird issue in calling Twillio APIs from Playframework 2.0 Java

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, twilio

I am trying to make calls using Twilio Java APis. Below is the code.

```
public static Result call() {
        Logger.debug("calling the requested number");

        Form<User> form = userForm.bindFromRequest();
        User user = form.get();

        Logger.debug("Information submitted " + user.toString());

         /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);

        // Get the account and call factory class
        Account acct = client.getAccount();
        CallFactory callFactory = acct.getCallFactory();

        //build map of post parameters
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        url = url + user.getCalleeNumber();
        Logger.debug("url is " + url);

        params.put("From", "+18054094292");
        params.put("To", user.getCallerNumber());
        params.put("Url", url);

        try {
            // Make a phone call  ( This makes a POST request to the Calls resource)
            callFactory.create(params);
        } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ok("");
    }
```

So the code works in case I run it dev or prod mode using play "run 8081" or play "start 8081". But when I stage the application and run it via nohup I get the below error. Any guesses why this would happen. The stack trace is below.

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found
        at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found
        at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:139) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.14-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:110) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.14-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at controllers.Application.call(Application.java:42) ~[twilio-test-1_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:69) ~[twilio-test-1_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:69) ~[twilio-test-1_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:141) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
```

Comment: You may have two different versions of the `httpclient` lib in your classpath. You can check it using `dependencies` goal in the Play console and look for duplicate.

Comment: Thanks that may have been the issue. I added the library in the play application sbt build file and it seems to work now thanks...

Comment: Ricky from Twilio here. Incase anyone else gets stuck here we put together a blog post on [getting started with Twilio and the Play framework](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/08/play-with-twilio.html). Getting the dependencies configured correctly up front was a little tricky for me too.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Ricky from Twilio here. Incase anyone else gets stuck here we put
>   together a blog post on getting started with [Twilio and the Play
>   framework.](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/08/play-with-twilio.html) Getting the dependencies configured correctly up front was
>   a little tricky for me too.

You'll need the [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) to get started.